# Is network available in Android?

Tags: java, android, authentication, networking, android-networking

I have this block of code I am using to test if there is a network connection before I start downloading some files. The problem I have is that I'm also testing on networks that require a web-based log-in form (similar to hotels, and airports, and even airplanes). This piece of code that I'm using is totally useless for this kind of scenario. The network reports that it `isAvailable` and `isConnected` in these cases. This of course is a problem, because I start a async network connection that fails. I was wondering if anyone knows anything I can do to make sure that I am "truly" connected, or if anyone has any advice on this subject.

Here is my block of code:

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

Log.e("", "Network info: "+networkInfo+" toString?: "+networkInfo.toString());
Log.e("", "getTypeName: "+networkInfo.getTypeName());
Log.e("", "isAvailable: "+networkInfo.isAvailable());
Log.e("", "isConnected: "+networkInfo.isConnected());
```

---

Here are my use cases where I have tried my block of code and the results.

### 1x signal on Verizon

```
Network info: NetworkInfo: type: mobile[CDMA - 1xRTT], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: connected, extra: , roaming: false, failover: true, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false 

toString?: NetworkInfo: type: mobile[CDMA - 1xRTT], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: connected, extra: , roaming: false, failover: true, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false

getTypeName: mobile
isAvailable: true
isConnected: true
```

### 3G signal on Verizon

```
 Network info: NetworkInfo: type: mobile[CDMA - eHRPD], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: linkPropertiesChanged, extra: VZWINTERNET, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false

 toString?: NetworkInfo: type: mobile[CDMA - eHRPD], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: linkPropertiesChanged, extra: VZWINTERNET, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false

 getTypeName: mobile
 isAvailable: true
 isConnected: true
```

### Airplane mode on my device

```
Crash: networkInfo NullPointerException
```

### NO wifi - No mobile data (effectively airplane mode)

```
Crash: networkInfo NullPointerException
```

### WiFi (not authenticated):

```
Network info: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true 

toString: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true

getTypeName: WIFI
isAvailable: true
isConnected: true
```

### WiFi (not authenticated) 2nd Device:

```
Network info: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "myWifi", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false 

toString?: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "myWifi", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false

getTypeName: WIFI
isAvailable: true
isConnected: true
```

### WiFi (authenticated)

```
Network info: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true 

toString?: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true

getTypeName: WIFI
isAvailable: true
isConnected: true
```

### WiFi (authenticated) 2nd Device:

```
Network info: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "myWifi", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false 

toString?: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "myWifi", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false

getTypeName: WIFI
isAvailable: true
isConnected: true
```

As you can see, I get true for `isAvailable` and `isConnected` in the scenario where I have un-authenticated Wifi and authenticated Wifi.

Comment: The only way to be sure that you have a connection to a specific site is to send a request there and get a response. Write your code on that basis.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you. I did it this way:

Create two java files as below:

`NetworkConnectivity.java`

```
package com.connectivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Handler;

public class NetworkConnectivity {

    private static NetworkConnectivity sharedNetworkConnectivity = null;

    private Activity activity = null;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = null;

    private boolean stopRequested = false;
    private boolean monitorStarted = false;

    private static final int NETWORK_CONNECTION_YES = 1;
    private static final int NETWORK_CONNECTION_NO = -1;
    private static final int NETWORK_CONNECTION_UKNOWN = 0;

    private int connected = NETWORK_CONNECTION_UKNOWN;

    public static final int MONITOR_RATE_WHEN_CONNECTED_MS = 5000;
    public static final int MONITOR_RATE_WHEN_DISCONNECTED_MS = 1000;

    private final List<NetworkMonitorListener> networkMonitorListeners = new ArrayList<NetworkMonitorListener>();

    private NetworkConnectivity() {
    }

    public synchronized static NetworkConnectivity sharedNetworkConnectivity() {
        if (sharedNetworkConnectivity == null) {
            sharedNetworkConnectivity = new NetworkConnectivity();
        }

        return sharedNetworkConnectivity;
    }

    public void configure(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public synchronized boolean startNetworkMonitor() {
        if (this.activity == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (monitorStarted) {
            return true;
        }

        stopRequested = false;
        monitorStarted = true;

        (new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doCheckConnection();
            }
        })).start();

        return true;
    }

    public synchronized void stopNetworkMonitor() {
        stopRequested = true;
        monitorStarted = false;
    }

    public void addNetworkMonitorListener(NetworkMonitorListener l) {
        this.networkMonitorListeners.add(l);
        this.notifyNetworkMonitorListener(l);
    }

    public boolean removeNetworkMonitorListener(NetworkMonitorListener l) {
        return this.networkMonitorListeners.remove(l);
    }

    private void doCheckConnection() {

        if (stopRequested) {
            runnable = null;
            return;
        }

        final boolean connectedBool = this.isConnected();
        final int _connected = (connectedBool ? NETWORK_CONNECTION_YES
                : NETWORK_CONNECTION_NO);

        if (this.connected != _connected) {

            this.connected = _connected;

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notifyNetworkMonitorListeners();
                }
            });
        }

        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doCheckConnection();
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable,
                (connectedBool ? MONITOR_RATE_WHEN_CONNECTED_MS
                        : MONITOR_RATE_WHEN_DISCONNECTED_MS));
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void notifyNetworkMonitorListener(NetworkMonitorListener l) {
        try {
            if (this.connected == NETWORK_CONNECTION_YES) {
                l.connectionEstablished();
            } else if (this.connected == NETWORK_CONNECTION_NO) {
                l.connectionLost();
            } else {
                l.connectionCheckInProgress();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private void notifyNetworkMonitorListeners() {
        for (NetworkMonitorListener l : this.networkMonitorListeners) {
            this.notifyNetworkMonitorListener(l);
        }
    }

}
```

`NetworkMonitorListener.java`

```
package com.connectivity;

public interface NetworkMonitorListener {

    public void connectionEstablished();
    public void connectionLost();
    public void connectionCheckInProgress();
}
```

And finally, the usage:

```
NetworkConnectivity.sharedNetworkConnectivity().configure(this);
        NetworkConnectivity.sharedNetworkConnectivity().startNetworkMonitor();
        NetworkConnectivity.sharedNetworkConnectivity()
                .addNetworkMonitorListener(new NetworkMonitorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void connectionCheckInProgress() {
                        // Okay to make UI updates (check-in-progress is rare)
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void connectionEstablished() {
                        // Okay to make UI updates -- do something now that
                        // connection is avaialble

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection established", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void connectionLost() {
                        // Okay to make UI updates -- bummer, no connection

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection lost.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

With the above usage, you will be able to check for internet connection in runtime. As soon as the internet connection is lost, `Toast` will appear (as per the above code).

Answer (score -1):

try this:-

```
   private boolean hasInternetAccess() {
        boolean hasInternetAccess = false;
        try {
                //I set google but you can try anything "reliable"...
                //isReachable(1) the timeout in seconds
            hasInternetAccess = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com").isReachable(1);                         

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hasInternetAccess;
    }
```

and use this

```
 If(WifiConnected() && hasInternetAccess()){
      //Do background Work...
    }
```

Comment: how can this possibly tell if you're connected to a WiFi network that requires  second login, such as in airports or coffee shops?